# MySQL - Ignore query if table not exist

Tags: mysql

I have this table called `tableA` where it might not exist in certain databases. I want the the select query statement to be ignored when this `tableA` does not exist in the databases.

I have tried to select count from the information schema, but one of the `if-else` statement still having the `select * from tableA`, which will still give me an error.

```
    SELECT IF( 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableA')>0,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA),
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB) )
```

And also i need the select statement of the true-false to return me more than 1 column, but when i tried that, it will give me an error of more than 1 operands. How doi make the query to return more than 1 columns in this `IF` query.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. Might need a redesign.

Comment: Why would you want this? It seems odd.

Comment: Because when the report use in other client, some of the client don't have the table.. so need to tune in query so that can support all

Answer (score 4):

I must agree that your requirement seems quite odd. Anyway, your query doesn't work, because MySQL (and I bet all other DBMS too) first evaluates the query to check for syntax errors and so on...and for existing tables.

Either you just make this multiple queries in your application code or you create a stored procedure to get the data using prepared statements. Code for this would look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_my_data()
BEGIN
SET @table_name = '';
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'your_db_name' 
           AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name')
THEN SET @table_name = 'tableA';
ELSE SET @table_name = 'tableB';
END IF;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', @table_name, ';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Once created you'd then execute the procedure with

```
CALL get_my_data();
```

Comment: @user3551839 Feedback would be nice.

Comment: thanks for your solution :) But they changed the framework which will check whether the table is exist or not before actually taking in the query. So, do not need to do it in just query itself anymore. Thanks though :)

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer anyway, so that others know that the issue is solved.

Comment: SCHEMA_NAME is a table in INFORMATION_SCHEMA, you should use TABLE_SCHEMA from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE

Comment: @TejpalSharma Your sentence doesn't make sense. There is no table schema_name and what you suggest I already do, you just mixed up some names.