# MYSQL Union usage on table that does exits (yet)

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL Table1 and wish to create a simple UNION with Table2:

```
SELECT SomeField FROM Table1 
UNION 
SELECT SomeField FROM Table2;
```

I already have Table1 created and if I manually create Table2 it's working as expected (even when Table2 is empty). Now on the server (and other co-developer machines) Table1 is already created, but no Table2. If I push changes, the application will crash, because Table2 is not there and someone will have to fix it manually.

Now how can I write a graceful query (or some alternative), that does UNION with a table that doesn't exist (yet)?

Comment: first run a query to create table2

Comment: In short - the application is very complex and my example in reality deals with domains. So if the query fails, the application becomes unusable. I know this not the best answer, but let's not get into details - this option is not available.

Comment: first check if the table exists and then run the query with or without the union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

*You can not query to not existing table*

But if you are trying to work in team (what I assume from your `I push changes`)

Then DB changes (`CREATE TABLE`) should be a part of your **push**

Another option is to use different queries for different versions of your application. I am not sure what language do you use but for ex in php it could be like:

```
if (APP_VER > '1.0') {
  $query = "SELECT SomeField FROM Table1 
            UNION 
            SELECT SomeField FROM Table2";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT SomeField FROM Table1";
}
```

Probably there are other solutions, but since you don't want to go deeper with details I think nobody will try to help you. That is very wrong behavior: to ask help but with no details about your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! This partially answers my question - it's not possible to query non existing tables. Is there any way to check if they exists and use that in the same query?

Sorry, for not providing more details, but if I try to explain the whole system architecture it would be a very, very long text, trying to mediate between people getting bored reading and having enough information.

The idea with APP version is a good one indeed, however not implemented yet in our application.

The push send php code and mysql migration, however it has to be run manually :/

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138787/mysql-ignore-query-if-table-not-exist

Comment: and by the way to start APP versioning is very easy. you just set new constant and so far you will use it only in this particular case. But later on other developers can use it for some other reason. That is very simple and efficient way to resolve many possible issues between different branches/variants/versions of your application.

Comment: Thanks again, Alex, I will talk to other developers about it!